# ASP.Net - Percorrer RadioButtonList?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Tenho vários `RadioButtonList` num  formulário, no evento de enviar o formulário quero percorre-los e pegar o valor selecionado.

Tentei isso:

```
    protected void btnEnviarQuestionario_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Resposta resposta = new Resposta();

        // criar a resposta a partir dos dados do usuario
        resposta.RA = Convert.ToInt32(dropdownAluno.SelectedValue);
        resposta.EscolaEnsinoFundamental = txtEscolaEnsinoFundamental.Text;
        resposta.Expectativas = txtExpectativa.Value;
        resposta.Linguagens = txtLinguagens.Value;

        // percorre as perguntas para criar o vetor de alternativas
        char[] alternativas = new char[14];
        for (int i = 0; i < 14; i++)
        {
            RadioButtonList rbl = FindControl("rblResp" + (i>9?"":"0") + i) as RadioButtonList;

            //if (rbl != null)
            //alternativas[i] = Convert.ToChar(rbl.SelectedValue);
        }

        resposta.Respostas = alternativas;

        // enviar resposta para o banco de dados
        _respostaBo = new RespostaBo();
        try
        {
            _respostaBo.EnviarQuestionario(resposta);
            lblStatus.Text = "Questionário enviado!";
        }
        catch
        {
            lblStatus.Text = "Erro ao enviar questionário! ^_^";
        }
    }
```

---

Dentro da MasterPage que estou utilizando, depois da tag `<body>`, possui:

```
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="~/Home/Home.aspx" runat="server">
                    <img alt="Questionário" class="img-responsive" src="~/images/questionario.png" runat="server" />
                </a>
            </div>

            <p class="navbar-text">
                <asp:Label ID="lblNomeDaPagina" runat="server" Text="Nome da Página"></asp:Label></p>
        </div>
    </nav>


    <div class="container">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>

    <script src="../scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</form>
```

Na página que estou usando a MasterPage:

```
    <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

    <asp:Panel ID="panelQuestionarios" runat="server">
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group">
            <asp:Label ID="lblPergunta" CssClass="col-sm-2 control-label" runat="server" Text="1. Qual a pergunta?"></asp:Label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <%-- Alternativas --%>
                <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblResp01" runat="server">
                    <asp:ListItem Value="A">x</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="B">x</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="C">x</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="D">x</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="E">x</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:RadioButtonList>
            </div>
        </div>

   <!-- Mais 13 perguntas iguais acima, simplifiquei o código -->

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <asp:Button ID="btnEnviarQuestionario" CssClass="btn-success btn" runat="server" Text="Enviar questionário" OnClick="btnEnviarQuestionario_Click" />
            </div>
        </div>


    </div>

    </asp:Panel>
</asp:Content>
```

**`rbl`** está ficando `null`. Como selecionar o RadioButtonList?

Comment: Os radioButtonList estão com os nomes como "rblResp01, rblResp02, ..." O problema seria que não encontro-os

Comment: coloque todo o código `.ASPX` por favor na sua pergunta, [edite](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/234032/edit).

Comment: Bart é a pagina??? tambem

Comment: `rblResp01.SelectValue` não é só isso @Bart?

Comment: @Marconi depois de ter conseguido acessar o controle é só fazer isso mesmo! O problema era que eu não conseguia acessá-lo...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Precisa buscar pelo elemento acima até chegar no que está mais interno, ***exemplo***:

```
RadioButtonList radio = Page
    .FindControl("panelQuestionarios")
    .FindControl("rblResp01") as RadioButtonList;
```

com `MasterPage`:

```
RadioButtonList radio = Page
    .Master
    .FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1")
    .FindControl("panelQuestionarios")
    .FindControl("rblResp01") as RadioButtonList;
```

<sub>***Observação:*** preste muito atenção aonde inicia o controle pai até chegar o controle desejado.</sub>

Se possuir `master page`, sendo esse o pai de todos controles, a primeiro [FindControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/486wc64h(v=vs.110).aspx) seria:

```
Page.Master.FindControl("ID_DO_Elemento")
       .FindControl("ID_DO_Proximo_Elemento");
```

<sub>***Referencias:***</sub>

- [Método Control.FindControl (String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/486wc64h(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [How can i use FindControl method in asp.net? SO<sup>En</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3157788/how-can-i-use-findcontrol-method-in-asp-net)
- [Using FindControl() to find control SO<sup>En</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3731007/using-findcontrol-to-find-control)
- [ASP.NET 2.0 MasterPages and FindControl()](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2006/Apr/09/ASPNET-20-MasterPages-and-FindControl)

Comment: As tags do bootstrap irão influenciar então?

Comment: @Bart só os controles, que possui `runat=server`!

Comment: @Bart tem `MasterPage` nessa página?

Comment: sim, é um Web Form with Master Page

Comment: @Bart teste o código com master page que eu coloquei, se não der certo coloque para mim tudo que está dentro da tag `<Form>`

Comment: Infelizmente não funcionou. Adicionei os códigos na pergunta.

Comment: @Bar olha o segundo exemplo com master page foi adicionado o elemento acima! lembra dá uma verificada!

Comment: Funcionou! Faltava chamar .FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1"). Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

O Método FindControl não é recursivo, ou seja, ele não procura em todos os níveis da sua página. Verifique se o RadioButton está dentro de um Panel ou de outro controle que seja um "Container", se for este o caso vc deve procurar o radioButton dentro deste controle. Por Exemplo:

```
var controlePai = this.FindControl("ControleQueEnvolveORadioButton");
for (int i = 0; i < 14; i++)
{
    RadioButtonList rbl = (RadioButtonList)controlePai.FindControl("rblResp01");

}
```

Comment: Envolvi os RadioButtonList por um componente Panel do asp.net e ele não está achando esse controlePai...